# Can we implement IWAP reports with IBM Worklight developer edition

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-analytics

Can we implement IWAP reports with developer edition of IBM Worklight 6.0 ? If yes please guide me with technical document or any link. Is this feature only available with Enterprise or Consumer version ?
If yes then how can we implement/test this on development environment. And can anyone please provide me with list of features which are not available with developer version(one which comes into my mind is Application Center).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Operational Analytics feature introduced in Worklight 6.0 is only available for paid versions of IBM Worklight 6.0. There's a file (`analytics.zip`) in the resulting IBM Installation Manager output folder that contains everything you need to setup the IBM Websphere Analytics Platform (IWAP). Once you have IWAP installed, you will need to modify a couple of properties inside `worklight.properties` which, among other things, tell the Worklight Server where to send the analytics data.

Regarding features found only in paid versions, beside Application Center and Operational Analytics, ability to use other DBMS (MySQL, DB2, etc.) and Application Servers (WAS, Tomcat, etc.). There are also Ant scripts that aim to help with common tasks like deployments.

**More**

- [InfoCenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.getstart.doc/what_s_new/c_wn_operational_analytics.html)
- [Getting Started Module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/10_03_Operational_Analytics.pdf)